# Web/Android/iOS - internal links - looking for ideas/solution.

Tags: android, .net, json, wcf, ckeditor

I will describe first what we have now:

- CMS - to populate database with drugs(meds) descriptions. Drug name as
  textbox and CKEditor for description in HTML format.
- WCF - export database to JSON
- Android app- list of drugs and then webview to display drug description
  in HTML format.

We need find solution to create inner links (i.e: drug name) in drug descriptions which will lead to mentioned drug description page.

Is there any way to achieve that with our current approach?

Even If I find a way how to create this feature in CMS (probably I will use hash tags to distinguish between external and internal links) still I have no idea how to get this functionality in Android app.

If this is risky or hard to add this feature to our current setup can you guys at least give me a idea how it should be build to apply this internal link feature. 
I never did this before so I even have no idea where to start.
Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have your links in CMS have a custom href format - something like drug://drugid

and than in the android app (webview where you load the description, override `shouldOverrideUrlLoading`)

```
webView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {
    @Override
    public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
        if (url.startsWith("drug://")) {
            //this is where the click to that href will be intercepted
            //extract the id from url and do whatever you want with it
            return true; //disable the webview to load that url
        }
        return false;
    }
});
```

For IOS devices override `shouldStartLoadWithRequest`:

```
- (BOOL)WebView:(UIWebView *)myWebView shouldStartLoadWithRequest:(NSURLRequest *)request          navigationType:(UIWebViewNavigationType)navigationType {

    if([[request.URL absoluteString] hasPrefix:@"drug://"]) {
        //this is where the click to that href will be intercepted
        //extract the id from url and do whatever you want with it
        return NO;  //disable the webview to load that url
    }
    return YES;
}
```

Comment: Hi. Thaks for advices. More or less I figured out this part. I think add this prefix to CKEditor as "a href" type is possible and use ID as reference. This is a relatively easy part (however making it working on web version - CMS and app version will be challenge).
I know as well how to override url source(HTML source). More important is how to make this "a href" click able with java listener to call intent (screen) with drug description. Which HTML control will work with java?

Comment: You would use WebView control for android http://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebView.html

Comment: One more question. Can I call javascript from webview? I have idea to create in CMS "a href" drug://12 " with OnClik call method getDrug(12). Then in android create javascript method getDrug(int) which will display drug with this ID. Is this will work? How about efficiency and webview generate time?

Comment: You wouldn't have to use javascript, use intent with that Id in shouldOverrideUrlLoading and redirect to new view where you would show the drug description. But you can intercept javascript as well - http://developer.android.com/guide/webapps/webview.html#BindingJavaScript

Comment: I just realize that I no need to call SQLite to get a drug info. I could use exact url to CMS drug page in webView. However this will required internet connection and one of condition is offline access.

Comment: Im not sure if I properly understand shouldOverrideUrlLoading() method. This could be called when url or html data is loaded into webView or when "a href" is clicked? Is there any way to override any click on any "a href" in webView not when is loaded but when "a href" was clicked?

Comment: shouldOverrideUrlLoading would be called if you click on href as well

Comment: That is perfect. Thank you so much for all your advices. Im going to test it soon. I will let you know how it work for me.